# WordPress session not working other than home page

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I tried to use Session variable on a WordPress website themes function.php file. It's working for the home page but not on the other pages.

Below is my code wrote on WordPress function.php file. Where on the home.php there is a custom login is there to get website access through access code.

```
add_action('init', 'start_session', 1);

function start_session() {
if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();

 }
}
 add_action('wp_logout','end_session');
 add_action('wp_login','end_session');
 add_action('end_session_action','end_session');

function end_session() {
 session_destroy();
}

$rand = $_GET['rand'];
  $id = $_GET['ID'];
  $_SESSION['invitation'] = $rand;
  $_SESSION['code'] = $id;

if (!isset($_SESSION['invitation']) && !isset($_SESSION['id']) ) {
    header("Location: https://www.website.com/home.php");

}
```

Comment: Why are you starting the session in an action? Just start it in the top of the file. No need to wait. It should be started rather sooner than later.

Comment: I think WordPress with PHP 7.2 has some issues its not working if i am immediately starting the session with code.

 session_start();
  $rand = $_GET['rand'];
  $id = $_GET['ID'];
  $_SESSION['invitation'] = $rand;
  $_SESSION['code'] = $id;

  if (!isset($_SESSION['invitation']) && !isset($_SESSION['id']) ) {
 header("Location: https://www.website.com/home.php");
 
 }

Answer (score 0):

I see where's the issue.

Inorder to maintain the session throughout you have to mention `session_start()` at the beginning of all the other pages. In wordpress you could easily achieve that by placing `session_start()` inside the **header.php** so that whenever you open a new page the session keeps its state so that you can easily access what's in your session in all pages.

Note: **Make sure that you place the `session_start()` before loading the functions.php**
*For more details on session_start() : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php*

I hope this solves your problem .. !! :)

Comment: I had moved all code to header having same problem.Also alone session_start(); does not help.

Comment: I doubt you updated the wrong header. To make sure what I said will work I advise you to put the session_start() at the begining of any other page you want to test and see if that helps. Then we can figure out the header part. First lets make sure this is the solution.